# How to use show with multiple elements not having an ID

Tags: jquery

I am not sure how to solve this and was hoping someone could lend some advice.

I am creating a blog and want to allow the user to grab a direct link to the post of their choice, through an anchor tag. When the anchor is clicked, jQuery should `show()` an input box with the link to the post.

The issue is, there will be many posts and none of them has an `id` for me to tie into. They all have classes but if I tie a click function to this class, all of the inputs will show.

Is there a way to get this to work without an id?

```
$("#show").click(function(){
 $(".target").show( "scale",
 {percent: 200, direction: 'horizontal' }, 2000 );
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="post-link">
  <a href="http://ex.com/link" class="link-url"></a>
  <input class="url-link" value="http://ex.com/link" />
</div>
```

Also, based on what Mureli suggested, here is my JQ after edits

```
$(".link-url").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.url-link')
   .show( "scale",{percent: 200, direction: 'horizontal' }, 2000 );
});
$(".link-url").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.url-link')
   .hide( "scale",{percent: 200, direction: 'horizontal' }, 2000 );
});
```

Comment: Anoop, I've posted all of it

Comment: it doenst have #show and target

Comment: Anoop, I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I took this example from something that was working.

Comment: html you provided doesnt have the tags with id "show" and class "target"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using class selector for both item and using [`next("selector")`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the nearest text box to show

```
$(".link-url").click(function(){
  $(this).next('.url-link')
         .toggle(2000 );
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

**Update:** Based on edited question

To hide input boxes initially call `$('.url-link').hide()` in document ready

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/QNJ4k/8/)

Comment: Thanks Murali. I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Murali, this isn't working. I can see the inputs on page load so I initially hide them. Now, I no longer see the inputs but when I click the anchor tag, there is no functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying to get this working. Is my code correct? I still have no effects. no functionality

Comment: Thank you Mureli. I am getting something now. I am also getting `TypeError: o.easing[this.easing] is not a function` and the page is refreshing

Comment: Updated, Now i am using toggle. Is it ok ?

Comment: @NaN, you may be missing to include jquery.easing js file

Comment: Mureli, one more question. Is there a way to get the textbox to show on the left of the anchor? It's opening to the right and covering the content. Should I use css?

Comment: @NaN, you may change html and use prev check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abinaya91/V4Xgq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If id attribute is not available, check if you can use the name attribute.